# Jenkins C++ Testing Wiring

Tags: c++, jenkins, googletest

I would like to run google tests on C++ with Jenkins.
At the moment, I am going through 4 stages split in two jobs

1. Job A, **Builds**

   - a) **Code** build (in my case produces libraries)
   - b) **Test** build (links with libraries above)
2. Job B, **Tests** triggered by A stable completion

   - a) Test Execution
   - b) Report Generation (via JUnit plugin)

I am executing Tests via "Execute Shell" that produces an XML report fed to Report Generation
I think my wiring is messed up because

- Failed test build (1b) would mark code build as failed,
- Executing Tests as a build step (2a) feels like a hack.

**Is there a clean way to Build-Run-Report for google tests** separate from code build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our project is structured like this:

In the makefile, we have the equivalent of

```
all: ${PROGRAMS} ${TEST_PROGRAMS}

run: all coverage

check: ${TEST_PROGRAMS}
        for p in $^; do ./$$p || exit 1; done

coverage: check
        lcov ...
```

On the developer machines we just "make run", which builds, tests and computes the coverage.

In Hudson (alas, we inherited it and I was unable to convince everybody to switch to Jenkins), we have three jobs:

- build: runs "make all" to build all executables and the test programs. If successful, triggers "test"
- test:  runs "make check" to execute all test programs. If successful, triggers "cover"
- cover: runs "make coverage -o check" to produce coverage info (without running the tests again).

We structured it like this for early failure: builds are triggered by check-in and can be quite fast, whereas running the test suite takes a fixed (and quite long) amount of time. Besides, if the code doesn't build, there's no point trying to run it :)

In my opinion, failing to build the test programs should fail the code build, because it *might* be an indication of a problem with the libraries, not necessarily with the test programs. You can create separate jobs if you would like to see separate status for libs and tests.

Hudson doesn't have a concept of "test". Running test programs is no different from running "make" (and if you run the tests from the makefile, no different from running compilers and linkers).